# required a single bean, but 2 were found in Resource Server with OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have implemented a resource server to verify the token and allow access to the protected resource.When I implement the `ResourceServerConfig` class and run it then the following error has occurred

```
Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - tokenServices: defined by method 'tokenServices' in class path resource [com/benz/resource/api/config/ResourceServerConfig.class]
    - remoteTokenServices: defined by method 'remoteTokenServices' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$TokenInfoServicesConfiguration.class]
```

**ResoourceServerConfig class**

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.key.public-key}")
    private Resource publicKey;

    private TokenStore tokenStore;


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(TokenStore tokenStore)
    {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices=new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() throws Exception
    {
        if(tokenStore==null)
            tokenStore=new JwtTokenStore(tokenConverter());

        return tokenStore;
    }

    private JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter() throws Exception
    {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter=new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setVerifierKey(getPublicKeyAsString());
        return converter;
    }

    private String getPublicKeyAsString() throws Exception
    {
       return IOUtils.toString(publicKey.getInputStream(),UTF_8);
    }
}
```

But in this case, I can not use `@Primary` or `@Qualifier` annotation to provide priority for a particular bean instance. I need to execute both the bean instances when the config class is running and how can i do it without using `@Primary` or `@Qualifier` annotation?

Comment: in my opinion you dont need tokenServices bean (just comment it), spring autoconf already provided one

Comment: @vlcekmi3 i dont think that is a good idea since `RemoteTokenServices` is vrey limited in purpose. Are you using `security.oauth2.*` in your property files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error stack, it seems that you are having `RemoteTokenServices` injected automatically. It is  used to query the `/check_token` endpoint to obtain the contents of an access token(*scopes, authority*... etc). The automatic auto-wiring of this class may be due to the use of `security.oauth2.*` properties. It can be disabled by using `prefer-token-info: false`.

```
public class RemoteTokenServices implements ResourceServerTokenServices {}
public class DefaultTokenServices implements AuthorizationServerTokenServices, ResourceServerTokenServices,
        ConsumerTokenServices, InitializingBean {}
```

Both classes implement `ResourceServerTokenServices`, so `DefaultTokenServices` could be used instead of `RemoteTokenServices` without an issue. check here for how `ResourceServer` handles `security.oauth2.*` properties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server